# transform: translate doesn't work as expected with viewport units

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create animation where at the start brand logo is at the middle of the screen and at the end it moves to it's position in navbar. I decided to `transform: translate` with viewport units. But it doesn't stay in center. On wider screen it sticks to right side and on smaller screen it's a little bit off center. Also `position: absolute` isn't an option since I can't bring logo back to navbar.

Is it possible to center my logo in the middle with only using `transform: translate`?

```css
nav {
  max-width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto;
  background: #aaa;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.brand {
  transform: translate(calc(50vw - 50%), calc(50vh - 50%));
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="brand">Brand</div>
  <div class="links">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Profile</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="test">TEST</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial horizontal `translate` value can work properly only when the viewport width is less than `400px`

In fact, since your `.brand` element is in static position you can't use the `vw` unit for the X-axis when the viewport is larger than 400px because your starting point is not (0, 0) of the viewport, but it's (0, 0) of the `nav` element: in this case the horizontal offset is `calc(200px - 50%)` — since the parent `max-width` is `400px`

```css
nav {
  max-width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto;
  background: #aaa;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.brand {
  transform: translate(calc(50vw - 50%), calc(50vh - 50%));
  animation: backtohome 2s linear 1s forwards;
}

@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .brand {
     transform: translate(calc(200px - 50%), calc(50vh - 50%));
  }
}


@keyframes backtohome {
  100% { transform: translate(0, 0); }
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="brand">Brand</div>
  <div class="links">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Profile</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="test">TEST</div>
```

Comment: That makes sense now. Didn't considered elements initial position as starting point. Thought that viewport units might work as absolute positioning. Thanks